# On the division and multiplication of matrices in python

Tags: python, matlab

Here the question with details and I think it's clearer,

suppose I have a matrix `h` of size `4 x 4` , and a vector of `x` of size `4 x 1`, if we have `y` is the output of multiplication between `h` and `x` which means  `y = h * x;` whose size is `1 x 4`. So when I multiply again the inverse of every column in `h` by vector `y`, I should be able to get a vector equivalent of vector `x` which means `$x = h^{-1} * y $`. But unfortunately, I can't get that in python.

for example, let's first do that in MATLAB:

```
clear all 
clc 

h = (randn(4,4) + 1j*randn(4,4));  %any matrix of 4 x 4 
x = [1 + 1j ; 0; 0 ; 0];           % a vector of 4 x 1 

y = h * x ;                       % y is the output of multiplication 
x2 = [];
for ii = 1 : 4 
    x1 = pinv(h(:,ii))*y;        %multiply every column of h^(-1) with y  
    x2 = [x2 x1];                % the output
end
```

in that case, the output `x2` is as expected, a vector `1 x 4` as below:

```
x2 =

   1.0000 + 1.0000i   0.7249 + 0.5054i  -0.0202 + 0.0104i   0.2429 + 0.0482i
```

In MATLAB, that's ok.

Now let's do that in python:

```
import numpy as np

h = np.random.randn(4,4) + 1j*np.random.randn(4,4)
x = [[1+1j],[0+0j],[0+0j],[0+0j]]
y = h.dot(x)

x2 = []
for ii in range(4):
    x1 = np.divide(y, h[:,ii])
    x2.append(x1)
    print(x2)
```

Although `x2` is supposed to be a vector of dimension `1 x 4` similar as in output of above MATLAB code, but in that case, I get `x2` a matrix of size `4 x 4`   !!

please any help.

Comment: Two issues you are getting wrong: `np.divide()` is element-wise and MATLAB is col major (FORTRAN-style), while NumPy is row major (C-style).

Comment: Try `extend` instead of `append`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend

Comment: @Renat, I tried but I get the same issue. !

Comment: @norok2 So, please how can I solve that ? you mean to use y = h * x directly?   I get the final output also 4 x 4 matrix instead of vector of 1 x 4 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- [`np.divide()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html) is for element-wise division, you may be looking for [`np.linalg.pinv()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) instead.
- MATLAB is col major (FORTRAN-style), while NumPy is row major (C-style) so getting a `list` as a NumPy array will get you to a shape `(n,)` with `n` the length of the list and not an object of size `(1, n)` as MATLAB would.

The Python code equivalent (sort of, I'll do preallocation) to your MATLAB one, would be:

```
import numpy as np

h = np.random.randn(4, 4) + 1j * np.random.randn(4, 4)
x = np.array([[1 + 1j], [0 + 0j], [0 + 0j], [0 + 0j]])
# y = h.dot(x)  <-- now NumPy supports also `@` in place of `np.dot()`
y = h @ x

x2 = np.zeros((1, 4), dtype=np.complex)
for i in range(4):
    x2[0, i] = np.linalg.pinv(h[:, i:i + 1]) @ y
```

as you can see, the shape of the output is enforced right away.